# p:spacer width is changing based on screen resolution

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `p:spacer` in my xhtml file to create some empty space in the left side of the Panel Grid, and right side I have two buttons. The alignment works fine for the resolution (1366 X 768 screens). But if the page is opened on a screen with a resolution 1280 X 1024 using IE 10 browser, the left side space increases and the right side buttons goes out of the view and a horizontal scroll bar appears. I don't want users to scroll to see the buttons. Sample code is given below.

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{dataBean.userList}" var="j" activeIndex="null">
   <p:tab title="#{j.department} - #{j.userCount}">
   <p:panelGrid columns="2">
   <p:column>
      <p:spacer width="1050" height="5" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column>
```

How to put the space that will adjust based on the resolution ?

Using PrimeFaces 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `p:spacer` for that particular case. Instead, you can play with styles to achieve what you want to do. This will work:

Use this style (put it wherever you have your css):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .grid{width: 100%;}
    .column1{width: 100%;}
    .column2{}
</style>
```

And use it in the `styleClass` and `columnClasses` attributes of the `p:panelGrid` like this:

```
<p:accordionPanel value="#{dataBean.userList}" var="j" activeIndex="null">
    <p:tab title="#{j.department} - #{j.userCount}">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="grid" columnClasses="column1,column2">
            <p:column></p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="hi"/>
                <p:commandButton value="bye"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

This way your first column will take all the available space leaving your second column with the buttons aligned to the right, and not depending on the resolution.